# get thumbnail original image

Tags: image

I need to get the original image for the image type attribute like the default one of `thumbnail` or `small_image` on the admin side.  You can't seem to use `$_prod->getMediaGalleryImages()` because if the image is marks as `excluded` then it an image will not show up there, which makes sense since it's to excluded it from the gallery.  You can do something like this

```
<?php
        $_prod = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
        $types=array();
        foreach ($_prod->getMediaAttributes() as $attribute) {
            $types[] = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
        }

        echo "PROD", PHP_EOL;
        echo  "id=>",$product->getId(), PHP_EOL;
        echo  "imageTypes=>",$product->getId(), PHP_EOL;

        //var_dump($imageTypes);
        $attrImgs=array();
        foreach ($types as $type){
            $imgHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/image');
            $filename = "";
            try{
                $filename = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_prod, $type);
            }catch(Exception $e){}
            echo " ==>",$type, PHP_EOL;
            $attrImgs[$type] = $filename."";//force string output
            echo "  ==>",$filename, PHP_EOL;
        }
```

Which will get you all the assigned images but, they are the cached url paths.  Not what I want.  I know the image name is in the url as `/n/a/name-of-original-file/cached.jpg` where `name-of-original-file` is the original name with out the but processing the string to get that is well not what I want to do.  looking at `Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_prod, $type);`  shows there is a protect var of `_imageFile` which is what I seem to need.

I can't seem to find out where I can grab file path or name with out having to pull it through `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image`.  What I want to end up with is a list of images and the type it belongs to.  I have the types done, but I can only get the cached url for the image.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$product->getImageUrl();
```

If you just need the main image, otherwise:

```
$product->getMediaGallery('images');
```

Which will return an array, even if marked as exclude.

Comment: yes, `$_prod->getMediaGallery('images')` return the list of the attached to product images regardless of if it's excluded which is nice and all, but I need to get what the original file is for lets say `small_image`, or some custom one I setup called `foo_image`.  Also it should be noted that "If you just need the main image" should be "If you just need the images attached to product".  Just to be clear, I'm not looking for the URL, just the file name/path of all image attributes assigned to a product, ie: (defaults) `thumbnail`,`small_image`,`image`  (custom) `foo_image`